# How to pass a String value from one servlet to another servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have one jsp from which I am getting a string value in servlet1 using 'request.getParameter' I want to link servlet1 and servlet2 and send the string value which i have got in servlet1 to servlet2.

please help.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: keep it in session then retrieve it using session.getAttribute()

Comment: Are you able to redirect to servlet2? Plz share the redirect code here.

Answer (score 9):

You need to set request attribute

In your servlet1.

```
request.setAttribute("attributeName",yourStringVAlue);
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("yourServletPattern");
rd.forward(request,response);
```

In your Servlet2

```
String someName = (String)request.getAttribute("attributeName");
```

Comment: RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("yourServletPattern"); Here what is the "yourServletPattern" is ity servlet2 name ? How to set ?

Comment: yourServletPattern is your servlet pattern as you configure in web.xml. your servlets needs to be configured in web.xml. For further info, you can refer this tutorial. http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/11/mvc-architecture-with-servlets-and-jsp/

Answer (score 2):

In Servlet 1 :

```
request.setAttribute("myAwesomeAttributeName",myAwesomeAttributeValue);
```

then recieve it in servlet 2 by

```
request.getAttribute("myAwesomeAttributeName");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ServletContext`

In your Servlet 1 use `setAttribute`

```
ServletContext servletcontext = getServletContext();
servletcontext.setAttribute("Email", email);
```

In your servlet 2 use `getAttribute`

```
ServletContext servletcontext = getServletContext();
String ReferMail = (String)sc.getAttribute("Email");
```

Comment: Bad advice. This only works fine if the web application is used by max only one user simultaneously.

Comment: I was learning these on my local server. when i use  setAttribute and getAttribute directly , the values are inserting as null in my database(MySQL).That's why i used servletContext. Thanks for the response.