# How to pass a String value from one servlet to another servlet using session?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Please i cheked for the answer of this question and i found this one : [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946277/how-to-pass-a-string-value-from-one-servlet-to-another-servlet)

how can i do that using session:

```
request.setAttribute("attributeName",yourStringVAlue);
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("yourServletPattern");
rd.forward(request,response);
```

and to retrieve :

```
String someName = (String)request.getAttribute("attributeName");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You stated "using session".

Set variable:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("myId","myVariable");
```

Retrieve variable:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String var = (String) session.getAttribute("myId");
```

Comment: And finally, `session.removeAttribute("myId");`