# How to use a variable in preparedstatement for sql query?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am doing a web-application project in eclipse Java EE. Currently, my application returns all values in the database which stores personal information of employees. However, I set the default prepared statement to search the table where employee_id = 1234, instead of the employee_id of the employee that logs in. This means that no matter which employee logs into my system, it will only display the personal information of the employee with id 1234, as shown in the prepared statement below:

```
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select employeeID,  FirstName, LastName, Admin, DOB, Address, Email, HourlyRate, Gender, ALeaveBalance, SLeaveBalance, ActiveStatus, Role, BSB, BankName, AccNumber, SuperNumber, SuperCompany from payroll_system.employee_info where **employeeID = 1234**");
```

Note how the employeeID above is set to 1234. That means my program (see code below) will only show the information for that employee. However, I want the employeeID to be set to the id of whoever logs in (login is managed by another servlet. If someone can please help me, that would be much appreciated, thanks :)

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class PersonalInfoOutput extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            boolean st = false;
            try { 
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/payroll_system", "root", ""); 
                **PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select employeeID,  FirstName, LastName, Admin, DOB, Address, Email, HourlyRate, Gender, ALeaveBalance, SLeaveBalance, ActiveStatus, Role, BSB, BankName, AccNumber, SuperNumber, SuperCompany from payroll_system.employee_info where employeeID = 1234");** 
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(); 
                st = rs.next(); 
                if(st){
                boolean adminTrue = rs.getBoolean("Admin"); 
                boolean activeTrue = rs.getBoolean("ActiveStatus"); 

               out.println("<html>");
               out.println("<head>");
               out.println("<title> Personal Information </title>"); 
               out.println("</head>");
               out.println("<body>");
               out.println("<h1>Personal Information</h1>");
               out.println("<p><b>" + "Employee ID: " + "</b>" + rs.getString("employeeID") + "</p>");
               out.println("<p><b>" + "Name: " + "</b>" + rs.getString("FirstName") + " " + rs.getString("LastName")+ "</p>");
               if(adminTrue) { 
                   out.println("<p><b>"+ "Admin: " + "</b>" +"Yes" + "</p>"); 
               }
               else { 
                   out.println("<p><b>"+ "Admin: " + "</b>" +"No" + "</p>");
               }
               out.println("<p><b>" + "Date of Birth: " +"</b>" + rs.getString("DOB") + "</p>");
               out.println("<p><b>" + "Address: " + "</b>" + rs.getString("Address") + "</p>");
               out.println("<p><b>" + "Email: " + "</b>" + rs.getString("Email") + "</p>");
               out.println("<p><b>" + "Hourly Income: " + "</b>" + "$" + rs.getString("HourlyRate") + "</p>");
               out.println("<p><b>" + "Gender: " + "</b>" + rs.getString("Gender") + "</p>");
               out.println("<p><b>" + "Annual Leave Balance: " + "</b>" + rs.getString("ALeaveBalance") + "</p>");
               out.println("<p><b>" + "Sick Leave Balance: " + "</b>" + rs.getString("SLeaveBalance") + "</p>");
               if(activeTrue) { 
                   out.println("<p><b>"+ "Currently Active: " + "</b>" +"Yes" + "</p>");
               }
               else { 
                   out.println("<p><b>"+ "Currently Active: " + "</b>" +"No" + "</p>" );
               }
               out.println("<p><b>" + "Role: " +"</b>" + rs.getString("Role") + "</p>");
               out.println("<p><b>" + "BSB: " + "</b>" + rs.getString("BSB") + "</p>");
               out.println("<p><b>" + "Bank: " + "</b>" + rs.getString("BankName") + "</p>");
               out.println("<p><b>" + "Bank Account Number: " + "</b>" + rs.getString("AccNumber") + "</p>");
               out.println("<p><b>" + "Superannuation Company: " + "</b>" + rs.getString("SuperCompany") + "</p>");
               out.println("<p><b>" + "Superannuation Number: " + "</b>"+ rs.getString("SuperNumber") + "</p>");
                }
             }catch(Exception e)
              {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
            out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're inquiring about the very basics of prepared statements. This should get you on your way: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the value of employeeID from previous Servlet to current Servlet .

```
Replace id:1243 with placeHolder:  ? .
```

Then set its value `ps.setInt(1,"value that you got from previous servlet");`

> changes to PersonalInfoOutput.java :

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

            if(session != null) { 
                String employeeid = (String)session.getAttribute("employeeid"); 
            }
```

to :

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
 String employeeid="";

            if(session != null) { 
                employeeid = (String)session.getAttribute("employeeid"); 
            }
```

Comment: Hi :) I tried doing that but it didn't quite work out, do you think you could perhaps help me with that? :)

Comment: It should work . What does not work . Can you explain ?

Comment: No No, I'm sure it would work, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I don't know how to pass the value of employeeID to this servlet.

Comment: index.html is the login page -> Login servlet -> Validate class -> Login servlet -> employee home page -> View personal information (this servlet)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946277/how-to-pass-a-string-value-from-one-servlet-to-another-servlet here you can see how to do that.

Comment: Thanks :) By the way, what should my parameters be for set attribute and get attribute?

Comment: something like this : request.setAttribute("employeeID",ID value entered by user while logging);

Comment: It's still not working :/ I think I'm doing something wrong. Now nothing (none of the html) is being displayed. I don't think I put my set attribute in the right servlet maybe :/

Comment: You are passing values from LoginServlet to ViewPersonalInfo ?

Comment: It works now, but I need to configure the information transfer properly. It's going straight from the login page to view personal information. Instead, it should go from login servlet to main menu and then when user clicks button 'view personal information' it should getattribute and display the html in the servlet above.

Comment: not getting information displayed for particular user?

Comment: ok, I edited my post so now you can see all the files. User logs in at index.html then the employee_id variable is passed to the login servlet. Now, I don't know how to pass it all the way to the last file, EmployeeOptions.java which redirects it to the servlet with the html output and database connection.

Comment: Ok, If its this much complicated make use of HTTPSession . Here you don't need to pass any parameter anywhere. Just set the session with the employee Id once and use it in any servlet . Go through this example: http://www.javatpoint.com/servlet-http-session-login-and-logout-example . In Login .java use this: HttpSession session=request.getSession();  
        session.setAttribute("employeeId",employeeId);  and in PersonalInfoOutput.java use this : HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);  
        if(session!=null){  
        String name=(String)session.getAttribute("employeeId");  }

Comment: I tried it, but now it says employeeid cannot be resolved to a variable where it says ps.setString(1, employeeid). Can you please check my updated code. Sorry about this!

Comment: See thats a local variable you need to declare the string out that braces.Change it to :HttpSession session = request.getSession(false); String employeeid ;
            if(session != null) { 
                employeeid = (String)session.getAttribute("employeeid"); 
            }

Comment: I still don't understand, it's the same as what I wrote before.

Comment: we are declaring string employeeid before if.

Comment: see answer for the change .

Comment: I copied/pasted it and it's still returning an error in ps.setString(1, employeeid)

Comment: "The local variable may not have been initialised"

Comment: what error? Initialization ? change String employeeid="";

Comment: Ohh excellent, it's working now! Thanks so much for your help :) And sorry about all the errors :)

Comment: That was really too much work BTW! :) Glad it worked. Please study java a bit more these were really basic things.

Comment: I will! I'm still in high school, learning software design and development.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use parameters in your prepared statement, e.g. as follows:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select ... where employeeID = ?");
ps.setInt(1, 1234);
```

Or with a named parameter:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select ... where employeeID = :employeeId");
ps.setInt("employeeId", 1234);
```