# servlet Query String

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I am using query string for sending parameter to other page in form action tag
but when I am fetching the value on the next page, it is showing `null` and `null` is stored in the database.

My code is as follows:

```
out.println("<html>");
out.println("<form action=SubmitTimesheet?manager="+manager+">");
```

and on the other page I am trying to fetch the value of parameter in following manner:

```
String manager=request.getParameter("manager");
out.println(manager);
```

But it is printing `null` and further if I am trying to store the fetched value in database it is storing null.

Please help.

Comment: first you need to check `out.println("<form action=SubmitTimesheet?manager="+manager+">");'. Did you check manager having value before send to servlet?

Comment: Can you please check in the first page whether manager is null or not?

Comment: yes i have already checked that on the first page it is showing the correct value for manager but on the second page it is showing null.

Comment: how two pages are connected? can u post tat code? it may be the issue mapping from 1st page to 2nd

Comment: my first page code  is like this :                                                                                out.println("<html>");
  out.print("<form action=\"SubmitTimesheet");

  out.print("?manager=" +manager);
  out.println("\">");
  out.println("<table>");    and second page code is like this       String manager=request.getParameter("manager");                                     out.println(manager);
  on the first page it is printing the required value but on the second page it is printing null

Comment: @cr.7 check this link- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946277/how-to-pass-a-string-value-from-one-servlet-to-another-servlet

Comment: @cr.7 is your problem fixed?

Comment: yes my problem got solved i have use session object and passed the value of manager in session variable instead of query string.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the `manager` query parameter if the `manager` value is null.

Also remember to encode query parameters.

And finally, the value of the `action` attribute should be quoted.

```
out.print("<form action=\"SubmitTimesheet");
if (manager != null)
    out.print("?manager=" + URLEncoder.encode(manager, "UTF-8"));
out.println("\">");
```

Instead of the `"UTF-8"` string literal, you can also use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`.

---

**UPDATE**

In reality, you shouldn't add query parameters to the action of a `<form>`. The form will post all the values of `<input>` and other form related elements, so what you should do, is add the `manager` value as a hidden input field:

```
out.println("<html>");
out.println("<form action=\"SubmitTimesheet\">");
if (manager != null)
    out.print("<input name=\"manager\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"" +
              StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(manager) + "\">");
```

The above uses the library suggested by answer to question [Recommended method for escaping HTML in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion . i applied  your code in my page. but it is still storing null in database.It means the value of manager on the second page is still null.

Comment: @cr.7 I've never tried query parameters on a form action, so that may not even work. See update for correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

i have use session object and passed the value of manager in session variable instead of query string.
i have used the following code:

ses.putValue("manager", manager);

on the first servlet page and then on the second servlet page i fetched the value like this :

```
String manager=ses.getValue("manager").toString();

out.println(manager);
```

now it is printing the correct value instead of null