# How to send data from servlet to another servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

This is my simple code in servlet 1. I want to use this data in other servlet. How can I do that?

```
String nic = request.getParameter("nic");
String name = request.getParameter("name");
String mobile = request.getParameter("mobile");

List<String> ab = new ArrayList<>();
ab.add(nic);
ab.add(name);
ab.add(mobile);

for (String data : ab) {
    allData += data + "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946277/how-to-pass-a-string-value-from-one-servlet-to-another-servlet)

Answer (score 2):

> **If you want to use it immediately (in the same `HttpServletRequest`)**

If the other servlet's `doGet` or `doPost` methods are **accessible**, use...

```
request.setAttribute(String name, Object o);
```

add everything to the request object and call it like this,

```
new servlet2().doPost(request, response);
```

Else if the other servlet's `doGet` or `doPost` methods are **inaccessible**

Use the **RequestDispatcher**

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("servlet2");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

*Defines an object that receives requests from the client and sends them to any resource (such as a servlet, HTML file, or JSP file) on the server. The servlet container creates the RequestDispatcher object, which is used as a wrapper around a server resource located at a particular path or given by a particular name.* ~ [RequestDispatcher (Java EE 6 ), Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html)

---

> **If you want to use it in multiple `HttpServletRequest`s**,

Add the data into a `HttpSession`

```
request.getSession().setAttribute(String name, Object o);
```

this will remain until the user session is being destroyed.